# Flutter project taking up too much space on CI

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a private C++ repository that contains a script that generates Dart bindings for it. So I added the repo at git dependency in pubsec.yaml file like this:

```
my_package_name:
git:
  url: my.git.repo.url
  path: path/to/the/folder/containing/dart/bindings
```

The issue is that when I run `flutter pub get` it checks out the whole project(which is very big in size) and then uses the specified folder in the project.

Because of this behaviour I am facing storage related issues on my CI.

So my question is - Is there a better way of adding dependency that would only fetch the specified folder and not the whole repo?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your CI setup, perhaps a `git clone --depth=1 ${repo}` would work?

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt

Comment: So with pubspec dependencies we do not do git clone by our selves. Flutter/Dart does it for us that is the main issue here

Comment: Have you tried using the `ref` attribute? I am not sure if it clones less history:

Comment: Can you `ref` to a folder? I have tried `ref` with `tag` and `branch` but it still pulls the whole project

Comment: Oh nope, not that I'm aware of. It would just be a ref to a specific commit, hoping to clone less history, not a portion of the repo. This is a tricky one...

Comment: Perhaps the best way to optimize it to break your dep into smaller projects, however I am guessing that's a pretty large chunk of work, and not going to help your immediate need